# How to generate a unique transaction id in a shopping cart

Tags: php, shopping-cart

I am working on a shopping cart and a local payment gateway that requires each transaction to have a unique order id. This id is supposed to be saved in the database against the order details and sent as a variable to the payment gateway. My dilemma is on how to generate the unique id and how to save it before sending my variables to the gateway so that I can check that it matches when a response is received from the gateway's IPN. The variable in question is show below:

```
$reference = $_POST['reference'];//unique order id of the transaction, generated by merchant
```

Comment: I'm grateful for all the responses. Retrieving the last id that was inserted solves this problem elegantly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do not use md5() on uniqueid() it will actually loose on security. To append or prepend md5 value is OK.

That said I would stick to http://www.php.net/manual/en/pdo.lastinsertid.php to get newly inserted ID, but also generate uniqueid() with prefix parameter set to lets say 'username_' so that way it should be pretty much unique.

Answer (score 7):

Here is how i used to generate the random key, even though its bit lengthy you can achieve unique random key.

```
$id.time().uniqid(mt_rand(),true)
```

uniqid() - this will generate the 13 character uniqid

mt_rand() - generates random number by using Mersenne Twister algorithim and is 4 times more fast then rand()

uniqid(mt_rand()) - prefixing the random generate number with uniqueid

uniqid(mt_rand(), true) - to get more strong random i am enabling entropy of uniqid by setting second parameter to 'true'

$id.time().uniqid(mt_rand(), true) - here $id may be userid, productid or any id which you want to choose, time() will generate current unix time stamp, lastly i will append with my uniqid(...)

Comment: Great step by step explanation. Since I needed a random number, I instead used `time().''.mt_rand();`

Answer (score 1):

If you really want an unique-id, here is the code which I am using. This simple creates 7 characters string and if it already exists in database -> regenerate new, until it is 100% unique. uniqid() is not really unique id, you could put there your own prefix which could be mixed with my code, but alone uniqid() with putting it to base64 and md5 and sha1 and I dont know what else IS NOT unique.

```
function randString($length, $charset='ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz0123456789')
{
    $str = '';
    $count = strlen($charset);
    while ($length--) {
        $str .= $charset[mt_rand(0, $count-1)];
    }

    return $str;
}

$unique_id = randString(7);  
while(mysqli_num_rows(mysqli_query($con, "SELECT unique_id FROM table WHERE unique_id = '".mysqli_real_escape_string($con, $unique_id)."'")) > 0) { 
   $unique_id = randString(7);
}
//insert this id into database and use it
```

Answer (score 0):

Insert the order details into a table. The primary key of that table should have AUTO INCREMENT property set. Then retrieve the last inserted id http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-insert-id.php

Answer (score 0):

Besides primary key of order table, a combination of a string, year, month, day and 4 digit no. can be useful.

eg.

orders placed on 8th Aug 2013 could have following order numbers:
OS201308080001
OS201308080002

orders placed on 9th Aug 2013 could have following order numbers:
OS201308090001
OS201308090002
OS201308090003

where OS could be initial's of your store name, next 4 digits are year, next 2 digits are months, next 2 digits are date and next 4 digits (starting from 0001 every day) can identify number of orders each day.

Answer (score 0):

I would say that the way to make the most unique ID would be a combination of the current timestamp (unix using time()) and then append and/or prepend it with something like the current users username. This way it is almost impossible to create a duplicate. You could also add in the last inserted ID as well.
In my opinion the combination of these three is a simple method and will make it almost impossible for duplicates due to the fact that time() will change every second and a user is very unlikely to be able to add 2 orders at the exact same second.

Answer (score -1):

Something based on a table of your database? A column with AUTO_INCREMENT. You can fetch the last insert ID with PDO with this: http://www.php.net/manual/en/pdo.lastinsertid.php

Or something like

```
$reference = sha1(md5(time()));
```

Comment: if there are two users which uses the function at the same moment, the encryption will return a same $reference variable.